# php upload failure with move_upload_file()

Tags: php

I write the php to upload file and scan the directory to show them as links, the scaning directoy works well I can see the text files I created in the directory, but I just can not move the local file to the desired directory .No file shows up after execution.

I think the problem may contain in this line:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"/var/www/BlueTapeLogin/upload".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

What I really want is to upload the image to the directory in /var/www/BlueTapeLogin/upload
and my php file lives in /var/www/BlueTapeLogin/upload_image.php
How can I change the code to make things work? Thanks in advance.

Please see my full code:

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
try
  {

if (!empty($_POST["delete"])){
$delete=$_POST["delete"];
echo"we have the command delete this file:";
echo $delete;
$file = "upload/".$delete;
echo "/n***************";
echo "you want delete :";
echo $file;
echo "***************";
if (!unlink($file))
  {
  echo ("Error deleting $file");
  }
else
  {
  echo ("Deleted $file");


  }

}else{}
}catch(Exception $e)
  {
  echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
  }

?>
 <?php
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"/var/www/BlueTapeLogin/upload".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
 ?>

 <?php
$dir=scandir("/var/www/BlueTapeLogin/upload") ;
for($j=0;$j<count($dir);$j++){
        echo $dir[$j];
        echo"\n";
        $target = $dir[$j]; // This is the file that already exists
        $link = $dir[$j]; // This the filename that you want to link it to
        echo "<a href=upload/".$link.">".$link."</a>";
}

 ?>
</head>
<body>
<form action="upload_image.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"><br>


<label for="file">Delete</label>
<input type="text" name="delete" id="delete"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">



</form>
 <a href="http://localhost/front2.php">logout</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the webserver userid have write permission to that folder? What if the user submits a file with the name `_image.php` -- it will overwrite the script.

Comment: What is your error message?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a directory separator between `upload` and the filename, it should be:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"/var/www/BlueTapeLogin/upload/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

The permissions you show say that only root can write into that directory, and but the webserver is probably using a userid like www-user. You need to change the ownership of the directory to the webserver userid. This will have to be done by the server administrator.

More likely, there's another directory that the webserver is already allowed to write into. The server administrator should be able to tell you what directory to use.

Comment: I have just tried this, but it still give me the same result.

Comment: Does the webserver have write permission to the `upload` directory?

Comment: I haven't thought about this. How do I check it?

Comment: If it's Unix, login to the machine and `ls -ld /var/www/BlueTapeLogin/upload` to see the ownership and permissions.

Comment: It give me back the following info:drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 19 22:18 /var/www/BlueTapeLogin/upload. Does that mean I have the permission?

Comment: It is a linux machine.

Comment: looks like web server has no write permission on that folder, if it is not running as root.

Comment: `chown apache.apache /var/www/BlueTapeLogin/upload`  or you can give write permission to all (not recommended) like `chmod 777 /var/www/BlueTapeLogin/upload`

Comment: @bansi Only the superuser is allowed to use `chown`.

Comment: @Barmar Yes only super user is allowed to change permission or owner

Comment: Thank you Sir. I am already login as the root user.How can I change the permission for upload files?

Comment: @user2514364 see my earlier comment.

Comment: Great. Someone who has absolutely no idea what he's doing is logged in as the superuser. If I told you to do `rm -r /`, would you know not to do it?

Comment: @Barmar I figured out he is logged in as root.  user2514364 you should not login as root at your level (no offense), if the server is not just for personal learning.

Answer (score 0):

Check user permission to upload in that directory and try to make it simple. Just simply upload a file to other directory see it is working or not than check your code go one by one step.

Check return values check whether a warning is issued

**Return Values**

Returns TRUE on success.

If filename is not a valid upload file, then no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE.

If filename is a valid upload file, but cannot be moved for some reason, no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE. Additionally, a warning will be issued.

Comment: I have change the directory like /var/www it still unable to upload.

Comment: @user2514364 check return values